# Redis: How to store client orders in Redis Hash?

Tags: redis

I have complex Data structure of order:

```
orderId
clientId
itemId
totalItems
itemPrice
totalAmount
orderDate
```

I need to `find all Client's orders for some date` with all items and other data included.

I have found Redis Hash as useful in this case. But I can't to find a right solution to form a this DB structure.

So far, I think that I could make a list of orders for client/date as SET, and HASH all orders. So when I have to find client&order first I request SET data and than read for every HASH data in it.

Comment: did you check https://redisearch.io

Comment: @GuyKorland Thank you for your comment. Do you think it is more suitable to my task than Redis itself?

Comment: It's a Redis Module, and extension to Redis that allows you to add secondary index

Comment: Look at [sorted sets](https://redis.io/commands/zadd) , it would allow you to fetch a given date, but also by date range. Just need to encode your date as int or float

Comment: @LeoMurillo Thank you! It really looks helpful for me.